# Call a method for each element of a list using Streams

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Customer` class as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Customer {
    String customerId;
    String customerName;
    String primaryAccount;
    List<String> secondaryAccount;

    public Customer(String customerId, String customerName, String primaryAccount, List<String> secondaryAccount) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.primaryAccount = primaryAccount;
        this.secondaryAccount = secondaryAccount;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public String getPrimaryAccount() {
        return primaryAccount;
    }

    public List<String> getSecondaryAccount() {
        return secondaryAccount;
    }
}
```

and there is a `ManageCustomer` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ManageCustomer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();


        List<String> secondaryAccount = new ArrayList<>();
        secondaryAccount.add("savings");
        secondaryAccount.add("loanAccount");

        Customer harry = new Customer("123", "Harry",
                "checking", null);
        Customer jiya = new Customer("444", "Jiya",
                "checking", null );
        Customer rob = new Customer("333", "Rob",
                "checking", secondaryAccount);

        customers.add(harry);
        customers.add(jiya);
        customers.add(rob);

    }


    private List<String> addCustomerAccountDetails(String customeName, String primaryAccount, String SecondaryAccount) {

      // logic is here

    }
}
```

I want to call the method addCustomerAccountDetails for every primaryAccount and secondary account of the customer list.

so, basically the output that what I want is  the method should be called total 5 times like this

```
addCustomerAccountDetails("Harry", "checking", null);
addCustomerAccountDetails("Jiya", "checking", null);
addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking", null);
addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking", "savings");
addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking","loanAccount");
```

How can I achieve this iterating over the customer list using Java8 streams?

Comment: @Eklavya that is not a good question, it's about collectors...

Comment: @Eklavya I think nesting and handling `null` were the main problems here

Comment: Why do you expect the invocation for `addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking", null);`? "Rob" has secondary accounts that are not `null`, then? and are you intending to ignore the return type `List<String>` of the method `addCustomerAccountDetails`?

Answer (score 2):

With an introduction of a request wrapper class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class CustomerAccountDetailsRequest {
    String customerName;
    String primaryAccount;
    String secondaryAccount;
}
```

and change in the method signature such as:

```
List<String> addCustomerAccountDetails(CustomerAccountDetailsRequest customerAccountDetailsRequest) {
    return new ArrayList<>(); // your implementation
}
```

you can achieve this with customer `Stream` as:

```
customers.stream()
        .flatMap(customer -> customer.getSecondaryAccount() == null ?
                Stream.of(new CustomerAccountDetailsRequest(customer.getCustomerName(),
                        customer.getPrimaryAccount(), null)) :
                customer.getSecondaryAccount().stream()
                        .map(secondary -> new CustomerAccountDetailsRequest(
                                customer.getCustomerName(), customer.getPrimaryAccount(), secondary)))
        .map(request -> addCustomerAccountDetails(request)) // ensure invoking the method desired number of times
        .forEach(//do something with the result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need streams for that, `List` provides `forEach` method:

```
customers.forEach(c -> Optional
    .ofNullable(c.getSecondaryAccount())
    .map(l -> {
        l.add(null);
        return l;
    })
    .orElse(Collections.singletonList(null))
    .forEach(sa -> 
        addCustomerAccountDetails(
            c.getCustomerName(),
            c.getPrimaryAccount(),
            sa
    )
);
```

P.S.: I have used `Optional` with a singleton list with `null` element as default to handle the case, when the list is `null`. However, the cleaner solution would be to return an empty list instead of `null`.

Comment: Just curious, may I use streams here?

Comment: @Andronicus given that the secondary accounts are a `List`, it should be `Collections.singletonList(null)`. But that's a misuse of the `Optional` API . A `null` check would have just been better.

Comment: Of course it does, I just checked in my shell, thanks Naman

Comment: @Andronicus , thanks for it. but the solution doesn't include this case addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking", null);

Comment: @Andronicus this will include addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking", "savings");
addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking","loanAccount");. But I need only entry for addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking", null); as well

Comment: @codemaster001 can't you add it to the list: `secondaryAccount.add(null);`? I can fix the code, but it's not the elegant way

Comment: @codemaster001 why do you expect the invocation for `addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking", null)`? there are already secondary accounts associated with Rob, right?

Comment: @Naman, Yes, But the requirement is that, it needs both null and with each secondary accounts

Comment: @codemaster001 then you might want to question the requirements as well, not that I am denying its not possible to frame it, but that I doubt you are working on flawed requirements in such a case and this could lead into ambiguous results during analysis. for e.g. If I look at just `addCustomerAccountDetails("Jiya", "checking", null);
addCustomerAccountDetails("Rob", "checking", null);`, then I would never be able to identify which of them had secondary accounts and which did not.